# scala: generating tuples from a list

Tags: list, scala, functional-programming

I have a list `val l=List(4,3,2,1)`, I am trying to generate a list of tuples of the format `(4,3), (4,2)` and so on.

Here's what I have so far:

`for (i1<-0 to l.length-1;i2<-i1+1 to l.length-1) yield (l(i1),l(i2))`

The output is : `Vector((4,3), (4,2), (4,1), (3,2), (3,1), (2,1))`

Two questions:

1. It generates a `Vector`, not a `List`. How are these two different?
2. Is this the `idiomatic scala` way of doing this? I am very new to Scala, so it's important to me that I learn right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the first part of the question, the for comprehension implementation defines ranges `0 to l.length-1` and `i1+1 to l.length-1` as `IndexedSeq[Int]` hence the yielded type is trait `IndexedSeq[(Int, Int)]` implemented by final class `Vector`.

On the second part, your approach is valid, yet consider the following where we do not use indexed references to the lists,

```
for (List(a,b,_*) <- xs.combinations(2).toList) yield (a,b)
```

Note that

```
xs.combinations(2).toList
List(List(4, 3), List(4, 2), List(4, 1), List(3, 2), List(3, 1), List(2, 1))
```

and so with `List(a,b,_*)` we pattern-match and extract the first two elements of each nested list (the `_*` indicates to ignore possible additional elements). Since the iteration is over a list, the for comprehension yields a list of duples.

Comment: Thanks, is there any reason you use List(a,b,_*) and not just List(a,b)?